# Cardlayout With Jbutton Not Switching

Tags: java, jbutton, cardlayout

Hello I am fairly new to java programming and I am currently trying to work on a small game with a GUI, Right now I am stuck at an issue where I can only use a normal button with a card layout, unfortunately I want to use my own icon with the button and to do this I need to use a JButton. but for some reason when i use a JButton it does not get switched with the panels. I'm just wondering what I am doing wrong. I am programming as an applet with a IDE called Ready To Program.

```
{
   CardLayout PanelLayout = new CardLayout ();
   JPanel AppPanel = new JPanel (); //Main App Panel using cardlayout

   JPanel StartPanel = new JPanel (); //Start Menu Panel
   JPanel GamePanel = new JPanel (); //Running Game Panel

   JButton StartBtn = new JButton ();

   public void init ()
   {


      StartBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon ("StartIcon.png"));
      StartBtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      StartBtn.setContentAreaFilled(true);

      StartPanel.add (StartBtn);

      AppPanel.setLayout (PanelLayout);

      AppPanel.add (StartPanel, "1");
      AppPanel.add (GamePanel, "2");

      PanelLayout.show (AppPanel, "1");

      setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
      add ("Center", AppPanel);
   }


   public boolean action (Event e, Object o)
   {
      if (e.target == StartBtn)
      {
         PanelLayout.show (AppPanel, "2");
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems to miss a part of your code to be understandable. Where is your `PanelLayout`definition ? Where do you call `action()` fonction ?More over, don't forget that variable's name start with a lower case character !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frist of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. I have never seen a tutorial or answer in any forum that uses an upper case character, so don't make up your own conventions. Learn by example.

> I can only use a normal button with a card layout, unfortunately I want to use my own icon with the button and to do this I need to use a JButton.

A JButton is a normal button. What other kind of button are you referring to? It doesn't matter whether the button has text or Icon or both, it is still a button.

The button in your code doesn't work because you didn't add and ActionListener to the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and examples. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Write ActionListeners`.

Your code has an `action(...)` method. I don't know if that is generated by the IDE or not, but basically the code in that method would be the code in your ActionListener.

```
add ("Center", AppPanel);
```

That is not the proper form of the method to add a component to a panel. First all don't use hardcoded literal strings, use the variables provided by the API:

```
add (appPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Awesome! this worked very well, thanks for the extra advice as well, my IDE created the Boolean action method, and I was taught in my class to use it. I also was never taught to use Jbuttons, just something referred to as "Button", something not part of swing, as I was never taught that either.